# Authentication Failed Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to enable auth into my mongo server. I've already done:

-Configured security into mongo.conf

-Created the users(if use it with mongo -u -p..... from console works fine)

In the node server js my config is this

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/dbName);
```

Also I've already tried with

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/dbName,{auth:{authdb:"admin"}});
```

And this

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/dbName,{auth:{authdb:"dbName"}});
```

And always get this error:

```
Authentication failed
```

What would be doing wrong?

Comment: i am not sure but try mongoose.connect ('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/dbName',{auth:{authdb:"admin"}})

Comment: Hi, I've already tried this and still not working

Answer (score 6):

Try specifying the `authDB` like this -

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/dbName?authSource=admin");
```

Comment: Can you post how you connect using the terminal successfully?